# List shortcuts on my Android home screen

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Get Installed Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196776/android-get-installed-shortcuts)

Is there a way to get the list of shortcuts the user has on his home screen?

From my Android app..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt it - the home launcher does not have to be part of the Android system, it could even be a custom app that doesn't use shortcuts at all.

However, you could create a custom home screen launcher specifically designed to broadcast what shortcuts are contained, and it is possible one exists out there already. But this would obviously require everyone using your app to have this custom home screen.

Comment: I'm guessing all shortcuts are saved somewhere regardless of what launcher you use..